# Java ObjectInputStream Won't Read Object?

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, objectinputstream

I am having a problem where I can connect to my ServerSocket and send Objects (A custom Packet class to be exact) to my client, but when I use the readObject() method, my code hangs and doesn't read any packets.

Here is the Client code:

```
public class ObjectReaderThread extends Thread {

public void run() {

    Object obj = null;

    while(!ClientTest.clientTest.socket.isClosed()) {

        try {

            obj = ClientTest.serverReader.reader.readObject();

            System.out.println("Packet recieved.");

        } catch(Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); System.exit(-1); }

    }

}
```

As you can see, I am using a separate thread for my readObject loop. Can someone please help me identify what is incorrect? If any more code is needed, tell me and I can post it. Also please note that no exception/error is ever given. Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Here is the code sending the Packet:

```
public void sendNextPacketInQueue() {
    Iterator<Integer> queue = packetQueue.keySet().iterator();
    try {

        if(outputStreamInitialized) ;

        if(queue.hasNext()) {

            int key = queue.next();
            Packet packet = packetQueue.get(key);

            if(packet.getLocation().equals(PacketLocation.ALL) && GlobalVars.onlinePlayers.size() > 0) {

                for(int i = 1; i <= GlobalVars.onlinePlayers.size(); i++) {
                    Player player = GlobalVars.onlinePlayers.get(i);
                    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(player.getOutputStream());
                        out.writeObject(packet);

                    if(GlobalVars.debugOutput) GlobalClassVars.window.printToLog("Packet sent to " + player.getUsername());
                }
            }
            else {
                if(GlobalVars.debugOutput) GlobalClassVars.window.printToLog("Not enough players online to send packet to.");
            }

            packetQueue.remove(key);
            if(GlobalVars.debugOutput) GlobalClassVars.window.printToLog("Packet removed.");

        }

    } catch(Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

This is run constantly in a server loop:

```
while(!serverSocket.isClosed()) {

        ...

        this.sendNextPacketInQueue();

}
```

Comment: Show us the code sending the object.

Comment: Maybe outputStreamInitialized is false. Maybe there is nothing in the queue iterator. Maybe the location is not ALL. maybe the size of the online players is 0 (your loop is wrong by the way, since it starts at 1 and ends at size, instead of starting at 0 and ending at size - 1. That suggests me that this code is never executed, otherwise you would get an exception). Add traces in your code, or use your debugger. Also, you should create a new ObjectOutputStream for every object sent. Create it once, and send all the objects.

Comment: The code is executed, but only once and then hangs. The problem is "obj = ClientTest.serverReader.reader.readObject();". No code after that line is executed.

Comment: What do you mean? One object is read, but not the second one? What about the server side? Have you checked everything there?

Comment: No object is read. I am assuming it is hanging, waiting for an object to be sent. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. But I asked you to check a whole lot of things at the server side, and you didn't provide any answer.

Comment: I know that the Packet is being sent successfully. I think that there is an error reading it. I have been working on this for about 4 hours now, and I know what's working and what's not.

Comment: You know, but we don't. So if you want us to help effectively, tell us what you know. We can't guess. And frankly, I doubt the loop sending the packets is executed, because if it was, you would get an IndexOutOfBoundsException, given that your loop is incorrect. EOT for me.

Comment: If you need me to I could upload the Eclipse project or make a GitHub repo? As mentioned in the post, no exceptions or errors are printed to the console.

Comment: I find that impossible to believe. This code will get both an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException due to your incorrect 'for' loop limits, and a StreamCorruptedException: 'invalid type code AC' due to creating a new ObjectOutputStream per message. NB your reading loop should catch EOFException separately, and close the socket and break out of the loop when it is caught. Looping on while !isClosed() is not sufficient.

Comment: I changed a lot of how it works. I changed it to create the OutputStream whenever a Player connects, and use that with a Player.getOutputStream() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a lot wrong with this. First off I was creating a new ObjectOutputStream each time. Second, I was getting the player from the list using an int, instead of the username.

**Don't even ask how I made these stupid mistakes...**

Answer (score 0):

Your client code is blocking on `readObject` call. It waits until the next object becomes available in the socket. Though you are writing the object on the server socket,  your client will not get it immediately because of the socket buffer. For the client to get the object immediately you have to flush the stream on server side after writing every object. In `sendNextPacketInQueue` method add `out.flush()` call after `out.writeObject` call.

```
out.writeObject(packet);
out.flush();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already tried that. It doesn't change anything.